# Creating a LaTeX package that forces landscape mode

Tags: pdftex, landscape, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to create a LaTeX package that will always be in landscape mode, but despite using `\LoadClass[landscape]{article}` and `\RequirePackage[landscape]{geometry}`, I'm having trouble. I've boiled it down to the following minimum verifiable example:

`testlandscape.cls`:

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{landscapetest}[forcing landscape mode]

\LoadClass[landscape]{article}
\RequirePackage[landscape]{geometry}
```

`test.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{landscapetest}

\begin{document}
    landscape mode?
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex test.tex` does not produce a landscape PDF. However, when I change `test.tex` to the following:

```tex
\documentclass[landscape]{landscapetest}

\begin{document}
    landscape mode?
\end{document}
```

it *does* produce a landscape PDF. **Is there any way to force landscape mode without requiring users of my package to specify `[landscape]`?**

---

Here's my output from `pdflatex --version`:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Comment: landscape in geometry swaps height with width. So the landscape for the class gives landscape and the second landscape swaps it back.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If I were doing this, I would consider cloning `article.cls` or whatever other class file that defined the style that satisfied what I was looking for, and swap the dimensions for the paper size and text block to be appropriate for landscape orientation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that did it! you're a lifesaver i was driving myself crazy here — the preamble that I'm trying to replicate did both and it ended up in a landscape. If you want to write your comment up as an answer, I'll accept it